# JavaFX return value from task

Tags: java, javafx

I am a new JavaFX programmer and I am currently having an issue with getting result back from the JavaFX Task. I want to get an object from the Task. Here is my simple code.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final MyTask task = new MyTask();

        Thread th = new Thread(task);
        th.start();

        MyObject result;

        task.addEventHandler(WorkerStateEvent.WORKER_STATE_SUCCEEDED,
            new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(WorkerStateEvent t) {
                    result = task.getValue();
                }
            });
    }
}

public class MyTask extends Task<MyObject>
{
    MyObject object;

    @Override
    protected MyObject call() throws Exception
    {
        // some basic processing
        return object;
    }
}
```

I get an error that the result object should be final and if i do that then i cant get the value in the result object. i have tried searching on the forum and google and i couldn't find the answer. any help will be appreciated. thanks.

Comment: There are a lot of syntax errors in your example.  Could you please clean it up?

Comment: Shouldn't `return object;` be placed inside `call()` ?

Comment: i typed the code here so there were errors, its cleaned now.

Comment: How can you be sure that the task doesn't finish before you add event handler to it?

Comment: I have also tried 'task.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(WorkerStateEvent t) {
        result = task.getValue();
    }
});'

Comment: Not sure if this is the best way. You can use [`AtomicReference`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html). `AtomicReference<MyObject> result = new AtomicReference<>()`. Use `result.set(task.getValue())` to store the result inside event-handler. To fetch you can use `result.get()`.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha But when are you going to call `result.get()`? Since the variable is a local variable, you can only access it inside the method, and there's no way to guarantee the handler gets invoked before the method completes.

Comment: @James_D Valid point. There is no way to guarantee that the handler is invoked before `result.get()` is called.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't reassign the value of a local variable inside an anonymous inner class (or lambda expression). The issue is that you don't know when your task is going to finish, so you don't know when the handler is going to be invoked. The method you are in (the `main` method in your example) may well have finished by then, so the local variable will be out of scope. So it doesn't really make any sense to assign a value to it, as you probably won't ever be able to access that value.

You can, however, assign a value to an instance variable (or, in this case, a static variable). So if you move the declaration of `result` outside of the `main` method, it will work.

Typically, though when a task completes, you just want to process the results (updating the UI). So normally you would just do something like:

```
task.addEventHandler(WorkerStateEvent.WORKER_STATE_SUCCEEDED,
    new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(WorkerStateEvent t) {
        MyObject result = task.getValue();
        // now do something with result
    }
});
```

As mentioned in one of the comments (and as an aside), you should register the handler before you start the thread, otherwise you cannot be assured the handler is registered before the thread completes.

Comment: Thanks, it fixes this problem but I also understand what you and others have pointed out. I probably need to rethink about my program. I wanted to use the result of this task in another task. Does it make sense to have one background task that runs multiple sub tasks?

Comment: You can just launch the second task from the first task's onSucceeded handler.